# AT，RIL how to use

Tags: at-command

How to use AT at Windows Mobile phone not connect with PC?

Answer (score 1):

What parts of the AT command set do you want to use? What exactly is it that you want to do using AT? AFAIK, WM phones don't really have the best implementation of AT and you would be better off using RAPI.